# CMake with usual project structure

Tags: cmake

The error is:"CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:2 (target_include_directories):Cannot specify include directories for target "hello" which is not built by this project."

The project structure is:

```
-build
-src
    -CMakeLists.txt
    -include
        -util
            -util.h
    -util
        -CMakeLists.txt
        -util.cpp
    main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
```

I want to build the target hello in build, and here's my code(incomplete):

```
#project/CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(hello VERSION 1.0)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

```
#project/src/CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(util)
target_include_directories(hello PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_executable(hello main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(hello PUBLIC util)
```

```
#project/src/util/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(util STATIC util.cpp)
```

I'm new in CMake and I wonder what should I write in these 3 CMakeLists.txt. I will be thankful if anyone can tell me!

Comment: A quick review of your snippets looks fine to me.  What issue are you having?

Comment: You can actually write it all in one `CMakeLists.txt` as long as the paths are correct. Pick whatever is more readable for your project.

Comment: Offtopic: `target_include_directories` will use the current directory if a [relative path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) is passed, so there's no need to have `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` there.

Comment: The error is:"CMake Error at src/CMakeLists.txt:2 (target_include_directories):Cannot specify include directories for target "hello" which is not built by
  this project.". I have no idea how to correct it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error described in the comments results from target `hello` being accessed before it was created. The `add_*` family of commands creates targets while the `target_*` family of commands modifies existing targets. Create first, then do something with it.

In this case, we can clean up some more. The file `project/src/CMakeLists.txt` should look like this:

```
add_subdirectory(util)

add_executable(hello main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(hello PUBLIC util)
```

And `project/src/util/CMakeLists.txt` like this:

```
add_library(util STATIC util.cpp)
target_include_directories(util PUBLIC ../include)
```

This way, you will create a library `util` with its include path as "include". When processing `target_link_libraries`, CMake will make sure `util`'s `PUBLIC` include path will be accessible by `hello`.

The benefit of setting `util`'s (and not `hello`'s) include path is that any target linking `util` will get the includes. Otherwise, each and every target using `util` would have to set the include path itself.